# How to type function that take parameters single key:value from object

Tags: typescript

[How to type parameters in function(key, value)?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Koa0X.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)  Additionally, please review the guidelines for [ask] and what makes a [mre].  Right now the question needs some editing before it is appropriate for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

It would depend on what types you want there, but let us assume you want `key` and `value` to both be strings.

You could do so by writing this:

```
function changeObj(key: string, value: string) {
  return { ...obj, [key]: value }
}
```

Given your specific use case where a `string` or `boolean` are possible options for your `value` you would do this:

```
function changeObj(key: string, value: string | boolean) {
  return { ...obj, [key]: value }
}
```